# Image with border background image

Tags: html, css, image, background, border

What I want is to make a border that goes around an image. Right below the border on the bottom left corner have the non repeating background when I put the class "PayPalItem" on it.
So, say this is the
[image]
I would like it to look like this
[image]
Here is an example of what I  want in the HTML to look like and the basic CSS I have set up.

```
<a class="PayPalItem" href="#"><img src="../assets/test.jpg"></a>

.PayPalItem img {
    margin-bottom:26px; 
    border: thin solid #FF9933; 
    background-image: url(assets/addCart.png);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, which allows you to share the URL of the link with the PayPal button:

```
<a class="PayPalItem" href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
    <span class='paypal-button'>PayPal</span>
</a>

.PayPalItem {
    position: relative;
}
.PayPalItem img {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    border: thin solid #FF9933; 
    background-image: url(assets/addCart.png); /* Is this meant to be the button? */
}
.PayPalItem .paypal-button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -1.7em;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c5p5h/

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best bet is to add that link inside a div with the paypal button. Something liek this:

```
<div>
    <a class="PayPalItem" href="#"><img src="../assets/test.jpg"></a>
    <div>...PayPal Button...</div>
</div>
```

If you just want to use one link (avoid the div option above), make sure you add enough padding at the bottom for the image, set the background to no-repeat and set the position to bottom-left.

Comment: I don't know why, but it took someone telling me that for it to hit me. The thing with that though was the bottom border would go below the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Well your background is always going to be in the background. Note the foreground. There are a few ways to approach this.... But I would use an :after pseudo selector. This will prevent you from having repeating code in your html which is always better.

```
.PayPalItem {
   position:relative;
}

.PayPalItem img {
 border: thin solid #FF9933; 
}
.PayPalItem:after {
    content:" ";
    /* set your width and height to the dimensions of the add to cart image */
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    background-image: url(assets/addCart.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
    <a class="paypalcontrol" href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"/>
    <div class='paypalicon'>PayPal</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.paypalcontrol .paypalicon{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-top:-2px;
    bottom: -1.7em;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

    .paypalcontrol {
    position: relative;
}
.paypalcontrol img {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    border: 1px solid yellow; 
    background-image: url();
}
```